# MATLAB: Count value occurences in Col A, with conditional in Col B of a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have looked around and have found close solutions but having a hard time refining them to what I am looking for.

Given a matrix **`A`**

```
A = [12 1 0 ...; 
     22 1 0 ...;
      1 2 1 ...;
     12 1 2 ...;
      2 3 2 ...;
     21 1 1 ...;]
```

I need to gather all elements in `A(:,1)` when `A(:,2)==1` and `A(:,3)=={0,1,2,...}`.

In other words my solution for `A` would look like:

```
12  1 12
22 21  2
```

The code I have so far is:

```
B = A( A(:,2) == 1 & A(:,3) == 0, 1 )
C = A( A(:,2) == 1 & A(:,3) == 1, 1 )
D = A( A(:,2) == 1 & A(:,3) == 2, 1 )
```

Is there a way to concatenate **`B`**, **`C`** and **`D`** together without creating 3 matrices first, **such that** ( applying a pseudocode ):
 `B( 0,(1:3) ) = A( A(:,2) == 1 & A(:,3) == (0:3), 1 )`**?**

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I have a bit of a problem to comprehend your wanted output. It seems like if you have a matrix and want to do some filtering. Then you want to find all the values in column 3 with any integer output and finally get some magic output. Sorry, you will have to explain more. My first impression is that the problem is to complicated formulated and that this is the reason why you have trouble with the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as its fourth argument:

```
ind = A(:,2)==1;
result = accumarray(1+A(ind,3), A(ind,1), [], @(x) {x});
```

This produces a cell array, with a vector of values in each cell. In your example,

```
result{1} =
    22
    12

result{2} =
    21

result{3} =
    12
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use `ismember` as follows:

```
filter = A(:,2)==1 & ismember(A(:,3),0:3);
B = A(filter,1);
```

You don't need a separate `filter` variable to do this, I just tend to do that for clarity.